# Row tables in SAP HANA

Tags: hana

Do all the row tables are loaded into memory when SAP HANA starts?

I know that the tables for column can be specified as load to memory or on demand memory but my question is about the row tables.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't support lazy loading for tables of the row store.

Row tables will always be loaded completely during startup and can never be unloaded.